# fabric js active object not selectable

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to build a script that would allow somebody to enter a custom text and then scale it, change the font, and the color.
It works, everything works, except that it shows has an unexpected behavior: if I click on the canvas  outside of the object then the object becomes inactive and then I cannot bring it to become active again.

this is the page:

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/googlefonts.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.min.css">
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/589156f3be.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

<body>

<div class="container1st">
    <div class="outer2">
        <div class="center2">
                <span class="tb"><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Input text&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><input class="input" data-text="text1" value="text1" id="id_text1" maxlength="30"/></span>
                <span class="tb">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-font"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Font-family&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><select id="font-family"></select></span>
                <span class="tb">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Font Size&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><input type="range"  min="50" max="300" value="50" id="text_size" /></span> 
                <span class="tb">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-palette"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Text color&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><input type="text" id="text_colour" /></span>
                <!--<span><button id="unu">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Try it</button></span>-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position relative, top: 10%;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="outer1">
        <div class="center1">
            <canvas id="c" width="886" height="621"></canvas><br />
        </div>
    </div>
<div style="position relative, top: 10%;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

    <script>
var imageUrl = "img/cadru-01-ok23.png";
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = "";
canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageUrl, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    // Optionally add an opacity lvl to the image
    //backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
    // should the image be resized to fit the container?
    backgroundImageStretch: false
});
// google fonts API key: https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDk3o9XW7qKxy9-Oa1R7IUM2E_iJbmDhj8
// Define an array with all fonts
//var fonts = ["Pacifico", "VT323", "Quicksand", "Inconsolata"];
var fonts = ["Aguafina Script","Akronim","Alex Brush","Anton","Raleway","Modak","Roboto Mono","Merriweather","Noto Sans","Playfair Display","Ubuntu","Titillium Web","Noto Serif","Rubik","Crimson Pro","Inconsolata","Arimo","Quicksand","Heebo","Nunito Sans","Fjalla One","Oxygen","Crimson Text","Bitter","Libre Baskerville","Karla","Cabin","Josefin Sans","Hind","Saira Stencil One","Indie Flower","Source Code Pro","Lobster","Libre Franklin","Arvo","Abel","Mukta","Dancing Script","Varela Round","Pacifico","Farro","Barlow","Shadows Into Light","Abril Fatface","Teko","Monda","Acme"];

//add input box style text area
var text1 = new fabric.Text("Text", {
  id: "id_text1",
  fontSize: 50,
  selectable: false,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  text: "text1",
  fill: '#000'
});
canvas.add(text1).setActiveObject(text1);

//populate the font dropdown
fonts.unshift('Times New Roman');
// Populate the fontFamily select
var select = document.getElementById("font-family");
fonts.forEach(function(font) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.innerHTML = font;
  option.value = font;
  select.appendChild(option);
});

// Apply selected font on change
document.getElementById('font-family').onchange = function() {
  if (this.value !== 'Times New Roman') {
    loadAndUse(this.value);
  } else {
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", this.value);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
};

// Load all fonts using Font Face Observer
function loadAndUse(font) {
  var myfont = new FontFaceObserver(font)
  myfont.load()
    .then(function() {
      // when font is loaded, use it.
      canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", font);
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e)
      alert('font loading failed ' + font);
    });
}

//Font Size #text_size
document.getElementById('text_size').onchange = function() {
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontSize", this.value);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
//Text color #text_color
$("#text_colour").spectrum({
        color: "#000000",
        showPaletteOnly: true,
        change: function(color) {
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fill", color.toHexString());
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
        },
        palette: [
        ['#000000', '#fafafa', '#c5c5c5'],
        ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'black']
    ]
    });

//canvas controls some will be set to false later on
canvas.getActiveObject().hasControls=true; 
canvas.getActiveObject().hasRotatingPoint=true; 
canvas.getActiveObject().hasBorders=true; 
canvas.getActiveObject().editable=true; 


//text input on keyup
    $('.input').on('keyup', function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        val = $(this).attr('data-text');
        newtext = $(this).val();
        input = $(this);
        canvas.getActiveObject().set("text", newtext);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

</script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver/master/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>


    </body>
```

Link with working example: http://fradoti.fr/000/

I'm not getting any javascript errors either. Any help pointing out what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are setting `selectable: false,` to fabric.Text object while initializing .

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel kind of stupid now.